# How to change the bundle identifier in xcode

Tags: ios

I want to publish my app on iTunes.When i enter the app name and bundle id it shows an error that app name and app id is already benn used.I searched on it and only solution i got is to change tha app name and bundle id.
But the app id should be the same as bundle identifier in our xcode project.So can anyone tell me how to change the bundle identifer in the xcode project.

Comment: you can manage it in .plist file :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goto the settings of your app target. Under general section you can change your bundle identifier. Usually bundle identifier goes like `com.companyID.appName`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to change in your app target -> General -> Identity -> Bundle Identifier.

But if app name is written in gray color there then it is likely because you have a product name variable, something like .${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}, appended to the end of your bundle identifier under Target (your application) > Info (info.plist). Try removing that.